# Will C-based vs python-based sockets affect the latencies between nodes?

Tags: sockets, serversocket

If I wanted to optimize the latencies between nodes in a ad-hoc network would writing socket code in C vs python affect anything?

I currently have sockets written in python, but do not know if C-based socket code will help optimise my the latencies between my nodes

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

C vs Python affects only the user space part. If this part is significant for your application depends on the specific application.

For example if your application is doing primarily unidirectional transfer then one side only reads while the other writes and as long as this is sufficiently fast done it will not affect the latency.

If instead your application is based on a request and response pattern it will of course affect the time to get the response (i.e. the latency) how fast the application will process the request and create the response. Using a lower level language makes it possible to better optimize this part for speed - at the cost of added complexity and development time. But this is actually mostly irrelevant if the main performance problems are elsewhere, for example caused by database lookups or similar operations.

Comment: That explanation sided with my experiment as well, As I was using gpu's on both server and client, that computation overrode any benefits i observed using C++ over python